# Is this limit convergent?

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider these two limits:

$1. \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{k}$

$2.\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (1+\frac{1}{1+k^2})$

For ($1$), I would argue that the limit reaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$, since $\frac{1}{n^2}$ 'grows' faster than the sum.
However, I am less sure about ($2$). I would say this limit either goes to $1$ or $0$. My hypothesis is $1$, but I can't really argue that one. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: The two limits are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{k}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\int_{\frac1n}^1\sqrt xdx\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}(\frac23-\frac23\frac{1}{n^{3/2}})\\
&=0
\end{align}
For the second
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (1+\frac{1}{1+k^2})&=1+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+k^2}
\end{align}
now note that $0<\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+k^2}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$
hence $$0<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+k^2}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi^2}{6n}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct for 1)

For 2) split the sum up and you get 1/n × sum of 1 from 1 to n whose limit is clearly 1 and 1/n × a sume that tends to a finite number. So therefore the limit for 2) is 1